# Internalization Angular 10 @angular/localize, $localize is not working

Tags: angular, internationalization

I upgraded from Angular 8 to 10th version, now implementing i18n with built in module `@angular/localize`, everything is great, except I can't translate source code, as per guides I have to use `$localize` function in order to translate code in 'controller', in guides saying that after I use this function it should show me a warning with `ID`, so I need to add it in translation file, but it's not showing.

Below is example I tried to add.

```
test = $localize`:meaning|description@@introductionHeader:text`;
```

I used several options, added custom ID, added to translation file manually information(info about line and file), but it's still not working.

```xml
<trans-unit id="introductionHeader" datatype="html">
    <source>text</source>
    <target>Translation here</target>
    <context-group purpose="location">
        <context context-type="sourcefile">*******.ts</context>
        <context context-type="linenumber">31</context>
    </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

Does anyone know what can cause this problem, or maybe work around or alternatives ways, how I can add translation in code?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What's not showing? Could you add the HTML part where you're using the property: `test`? Are you using it as an `interpolation`?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply use "ng build" you need to have proper angular.json configuration:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "localize": true,
            "aot": true,
        }
}
```

and other settings from here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#localize-config